# Discord.py bot, how to send message once in an interval of time?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I try to create a discord bot in Python and want to add a feature when the bot sends a message every interval of time (like every week or every month), any ideas?

Comment: Set up a cron job. Here's an example for Linux/Mac: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925621/how-to-add-a-bash-script-to-a-cron-job

Comment: You can set a cron right in your bot script with [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using the [discord.ext.tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) :

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=1)
async def myFunction():
#Insert the code you want to be repeated here 

myFunction.start()
```

An advantage is that you can set before and after triggers with `@myFunction.before_loop` and `@myFunction.after_loop`